# How to implement a stop condition using threads in a static class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a project and I was having some difficulty stopping the program. I'm using a thread instead of a timer because I felt it was easier to work with. Basically, the problem I have right now is getting the time from the main function into the static function. Any help would be appreciated. In case my question wasn't clear, I included the important parts of the code with comments. TIA

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class InLineCustomers {
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main (String args[]){
        try{
            final long NANOSEC_PER_SEC = 1000l*1000*1000;

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            long time = (System.nanoTime()-startTime);
            final long genTime=3*60*NANOSEC_PER_SEC;

            while (time<genTime){ //Program runs for 3 minutes
                customerGenerator();

                Random r = new Random();    
                int timeValue=r.nextInt(10);    


                Thread.currentThread().sleep(timeValue * 1000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }


    public static void customerGenerator(){
        ...code here
        if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){    
            /**This doesn't working because the customerGenerator is in it's own static class
             * Would the program be more difficult to read if I had everything in the main method?
             * That's what I'm trying to avoid
             * 
             * time=genTime;
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The restaurant is no longer accepting any customers.");
             */

            stop(); //This isn't working because it created a different timer

        }

    }
    public static void stop(){
        final long NANOSEC_PER_SEC = 1000l*1000*1000; 
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();             
        long time = (System.nanoTime()-startTime);
        final long genTime=3*60*NANOSEC_PER_SEC;
        time=genTime;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The restaurant is no longer accepting any customers.");
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not creating a Thread anywhere, you're just using the main Thread.  There is no "main class" or "static class" here, just a static main function and a static customerGenerator function that both belong to the same class.  Seems like you're missing on more than a few fundamental threading concepts.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't answer my question at all. I'll edit the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

This shows a couple of ways you might communicate with a thread, perhaps the most relevant is the use of a `java.util.concurrent.atomic` variable to pass data to a thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong timer = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong((long)(Math.random() * 1000));

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                long timeValue = timer.get();
                do {
                    System.out.println("Customer does something");
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(timeValue);
                    timeValue = timer.get();
                } while (0 != timeValue);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException interrupt) {
                // whatever;
            }
            System.out.println("Parent says we're all done");
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(Math.random() * 10 * 1000));
        boolean do_it_the_easy_way = true;
        if (do_it_the_easy_way) {
            thread.interrupt();
        } else {
            timer.set(0);
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException interrupt) {
        System.out.println("Program halted externally");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is **one** way to create a Thread.  Normally you wouldn't use an anonymous inner class for anything non-trivial (like customer logic)